# Iam trying to make a stopwatch using reactjs. I have done it .But i need to make the time not to change when my refreshing the browser .How to do that

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make a stopwatch application using react. I have done it, but I need to make the time not to change when I'm refreshing the page. How to do this?

Comment: You can use localStorage to save the start time of timer and when refresh the page get the start timer from the localStorage and compare it with the current time to verify that the timer is completed or not. After timer completed remove that localStorage.
If you need detail explanation ping me here..

Answer (score 0):

`React` renders fully on page reload. So all `timeouts` will be newly created as you noticed.

For persisting data between page reloads, you can use `localStorage` which only refreshes on cache cleanup for a given host. It is a globally accessible Object which allows to store primitive resp. seriasable datatypes like `number`,`string` or `boolean`.

Example

```js
var storageKey = 'stopwatch-start-time'

var setStartTime = (time) => {
  localStorage.setItem(key, time)
}

var getStartTime = (time) => {
  return localStorage.getItem(key, time)
}

// when starting, persist the start time!.
var startStopWatch = () => {
  var time = Date.now()
  setStartTime(time)
  return time
}
```

So with the stored time, it's possible to render the actual time in your React Component as follows:

```
render = () => {
   var startTime = getStartTime()
   
   // If no startTime is present  
   if(!startTime) {
     return <div>00:00</div>
   }

   return <div>sopwatch runned for {(Date.now() - startTime) / 1000} seconds</div>
}
```

If you have problems, show me the relevant `react` code and I can help you to embed it. This is just pseudocode because you did not provide any code.